# Is Review.stackexchange messing with my mind?

Tags: discussion, review

I rejected a disaster area of an edit, and look what popped up:

> Congratulations!
>
> This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention.
>   You passed.

How many more Easter Eggs are going to sneak up on me?  :-)

Comment: I don't get it. You're not happy that you were congratulated on paying attention? or is there something I seem to be missing?

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ No, just a bit shocked (it's early in the AM for me) that this little goodie happened.  I suppose nothing the code gurus who built SE and SO does should surprise me, but there it is. :-)

Comment: You'd have got a different surprise had you clicked on "approve" for that edit :) Nevertheless, continue your good job of reviewing. The community needs such efforts from everybody :)

Comment: These just keep check on the robo reviewers that just click approve as quickly as possible to get the badge. If you're paying attention the edit audits won't trouble you (close review audits can be a little harder)